# convert categorical attribute into multiple attributes in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

For example, the Gender attribute will be transformed into two attributes, "Genre=M" and "Genre=F"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw4T9.png)
and i need two columns Male and Female ,assigning binary values corresponding to the presence or not presence of the attribute

Comment: Basically, [pandas get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) function will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks peeps ..very helpfull

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: You can make use of pd.get_dummies(colname) which will give you n new columns(where n is number of distinct values of that col) each representing binary flags to represent the value state for each row.
Method 2:
We can also use df. Colname. map({'M' :0,'F':1})
Method 3:
We can use replace command like df. Colname. replace(['M', 'F' ], [1, 0], inplace=True) 
First method is onehot encoding other 2 is similar to label encoding

Comment: Thank you ,It was very helpful!!

Comment: You are welcome :) Please do accept answer if its helpful to you. It helps to your own reputation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas function `get_dummies`.

> **get_dummies**: Convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables. [Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html).

Example of usage:

```
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))

pd.get_dummies(s)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```

Comment: It was very helpfull !!